# Can you order the listagg return value in DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I would like the listagg return value to be ordered so it's like:

```
name@email.com | 200000#500000# 

Not: 

name@email.com | 500000#200000#
```

Below is some sample code.

I noticed if I put the *('200000', 'name@email.com')* line first, it does what I want it to do, but I can't ORDER in a CTE so am a bit lost on how to get the same result.

```
WITH TAB (client, email) AS 
(
VALUES 
  ('500000', 'name@email.com'), 
  ('200000', 'name@email.com')
)
SELECT email, listagg(trim(client) || '#', '')
FROM TAB a
GROUP BY email;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using `within group`

```
WITH TAB (client, email) AS 
(
VALUES 
  ('500000', 'name@email.com'), 
  ('200000', 'name@email.com')
)
SELECT email, listagg(trim(client) || '#', '') within group (ORDER BY client)
FROM TAB a
GROUP BY email;
```